# Add a google account to your mail on macOS Monetery

Tags: macos-monterey

I was trying to add my Gmail account on my MacBook Pro (macOS Monterey v 12.1), but whenever I click on the open browser button the popup keeps on loading forever.

Answer (score 0):

- open `safari`
- go to `preferences`
- under `General` tab
- click the `Set Default` browser
- keep it set to its default click `Keep Google Chrome`

by Just clicking that button I was able to access the authentication window.
you can check the answer from https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOS/comments/qhxcz8/comment/hl7k377/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3